# How to set transparent background for Image Button in code?

Tags: android, background, transparent, imagebutton

I can set ImageButton background transparent in `layout.xml` using:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

How I can acomplish same thing using java code?
Something like `ib.setBackgroundColor(???);`

Comment: thx for asking, just needed that transparant line :)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This is the simple only you have to set background color as transparent

```
    ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 33):

Do it in your xml

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSettings"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/tabbar_settings_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

This should work - `imageButton.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 12):

**DON'T USE A TRANSAPENT OR NULL LAYOUT** because then the `button` (or the generic view) will no more highlight at click!!!

> I had the same problem and finally I found the correct attribute from Android API to solve the problem. It can apply to any view

Use this in the button specifications

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

**This requires API 11**

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Using `null` or `transparent` disables the button feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
ImageButton imagetrans=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImagevieID);

imagetrans.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

OR

include this in your .xml file in res/layout

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent
```

Answer (score 3):

simply use this in your imagebutton layout

```
android:background="@null"
```

using

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent
```

or

```
 btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

doesn't give perfect transparency

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use android `R` class

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.transparent));
```

and don't forget to add support library to Gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```