# To set background of Custom Layout with an ImageView to Transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I am building a Custom dialog box using the Android Developer docs [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) , for this i made a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rotatelayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#80000000"
>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/dialogimage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and i am inflating this dialog,

```
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)   getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rotate_dialog_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rotatelayout));   
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogimage);
image.setOnClickListener(new RotateLockListener());
image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
if(locked) 
{
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock_icon);
}
else 
{
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlock_icon);
}
builder.setView(view).setCancelable(true);
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setView(view, 0, 0, 0, 0);
timerDelayRemoveDialog(time, dialog);
dialog.show();
```

but still it appears as 
[image: how dialog appears]

I have tried all the help provided at the stack over flow

[Setting ImageView background to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710025/how-to-set-transparent-background-for-image-button-in-code),

[Setting transparency by #80000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android) and

[Setting Dialog window transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059068/android-dialog-transparent)

But none of them worked, it still showing up.

Comment: #80000000 is not right you should use #00000000 in linear layout

Comment: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @user370305 i used that too but still it remained black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use Dialog class for this,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.temp);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: can you tell me what exactly in that code is producing that black background in the figure?

Comment: That's the default theme for any "Alert" Dialog. I don't know how to remove the Theme from Alert Dialog, but this is what I use for Custom Dialog and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as the style of your View :

```
<style name="Dialog_Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```